# How to solve $\delta''(\vec{k},\tau)+\mathcal{H}(\tau)\delta'(\vec{k},\tau)-\dfrac{3}{2}\Omega_m(\tau)\mathcal{H}^2(\tau)\delta(\vec{k},\tau)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, leibniz-integral-rule

While self-studying a set of notes about Cosmology, I have encountered the following claim:

> We have the linear growth equation:
>
> $$\delta''(\vec{k},\tau)+\mathcal{H}(\tau)\delta'(\vec{k},\tau)-\dfrac{3}{2}\Omega_m(\tau)\mathcal{H}^2(\tau)\delta(\vec{k},\tau)=0 \label{1}\tag{1}$$
>
> We can easily confirm the above differential equation has a growing and a decaying mode solution:
>
> $$\delta(\vec{k},\tau)=D_+(\tau)\delta_{+,0}(\vec{k})+D_-(\tau)\delta_{-,0}(\vec{k}) \label{2}\tag{2}$$
>
> where $D_-(\tau)=D_{-,0}H=D_{-,0}\mathcal{H}/a$. The growing mode solution can then be obtained as:
>
> $$D_+(\tau)=D_{+,0}H(\tau)\int^{a(\tau)}_0\dfrac{da'}{\mathcal{H}^3(a')} \label{3}\tag{3}$$

First, I will explain the notation and the relationships between the different variables, that have nothing to do with mathematics and come from the physics background of the question:

- $t$ and $\tau$ are two different measurements of time, respectively named coordinate time and conformal time.
- $a=a(t)=a(\tau)$ is a scalar that depends on time.
- $H=\dfrac{1}{a}\dfrac{da}{dt}$ and $\mathcal{H}=\dfrac{1}{a}\dfrac{da}{d\tau}$, where $d\tau=\dfrac{dt}{a}$, and therefore $\mathcal{H}=aH$.
- The following equality holds:
  $$\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial\tau}=\mathcal{H}^2\bigg(1-\dfrac{3}{2}\Omega_m\bigg)$$

I am completely lost here. First, I don't know how to solve the differential equation itself, and then, it is not clear to me either how to prove that the expression given for $D_+(\tau)$ is a solution. I assume that the notes use a very confusing notation, since I understand that the $a'$ inside the integral is *not* $da/d\tau$, but simply a way to rename $a$ to that it is not represented by the same letter than the upper limit of the integral itself. So we would actually have, if I am correct:

$$D_+(\tau)=D_{+,0}H(\tau)\int^{a(\tau)}_0\dfrac{da}{\mathcal{H}^3(a)}$$

In order to prove that this is a solution of \eqref{1}, we would need to find its first and second derivatives with respect to $\tau$. However, when trying to do this by applying Leibniz rule for the derivation of an integral, given in the case of  multiple parameters by:

$$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial\lambda_k}=\int^{b(\lambda)}_{a(\lambda)}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\lambda_k}dx+\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial\lambda_k}\cdot f(\lambda,b(\lambda))-\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial\lambda_k}\cdot f(\lambda,a(\lambda))\ \ \ \ \text{where}\ \ \ \ F(\lambda)=\int^{b(\lambda)}_{a(\lambda)}f(\lambda,x)dx$$

I encounter a problem: we don't have here an independent integration variable and parameter, but rather an integration variable $a$ that depends on the parameter $\tau$. So I have no idea how to proceed.

I assume that the reasoning behind \eqref{2} is related to the fact that there are no derivatives with respect to $\vec{k}$ in \eqref{1}, so the solution can be written as a constant that only depends on $\vec{k}$ multiplied by the solution that depends on $\tau$, but I don't know why we can separate that solution into a growing and a decaying function of $\tau$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've dwelled on this for weeks and can't find an explanation or a way to solve the differential equation.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you may write

\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{a(\tau)}\frac{da'}{\mathcal{H}^{3}(a')} = \int_{0}^{\tau}\mathcal{H}^{-3}(a'(\tau'))\frac{d\tau'}{d\tau'/da'} \\ &= \int_{0}^{\tau}\mathcal{H}^{-2}(a'(\tau'))a'(\tau')\;d\tau'= \int_{0}^{\tau} f(\tau')\;d\tau'
\end{align}

so

\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{d\tau} &= f(\tau) = \mathcal{H}^{-2}(\tau)a(\tau)
\end{align}

Alternative expressions for \eqref{1} in [David Weinberg's course notes on Astronomy 873](https://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/weinberg.21/A873/notes8.pdf) (first eq. on third page) and [Rien van de Weijgaert's *Large Scale Structure (2009)* course notes](https://www.astro.rug.nl/%7Eweygaert/tim1publication/lss2009/lss2009.linperturb.pdf) (eq. 42) may be worth checking.

Comment: Thank you, that's an amazing idea you had there on how to derivate the integral. Using that, and after a long calculation, I was able to prove that (3) is indeed a solution of (1). Now I'm only missing how to obtain (3) from (1). Any ideas? It doesn't look easy.

Comment: No idea.  However, may I point out that Rien van de Weijgaert's Large Scale Structure (2009) course notes include several models for the growing mode solution. Section 8.2, in particular, seems to be relevant to the present problem.

Comment: Well, even if you didn't answer the whole question, your answer and recommendations have been very helpful, so the bounty is yours! Thank you very much for your help! :)